# I need to get script which compare the file row wise and list out the difference

Tags: shell, awk

I have 2 files, `A.txt` and `B.txt`.

`A.txt` contains service and version number pairs:

```
api 2.3
java 3.3
```

`B.txt` contains the same thing:

```
api 4.3
java 4.5
```

I want to compare the version and display it as a 3rd coloumn, like this:

```
col1  col2 col3    col4
api   2.3   4.3     no match
java  3.3   4.5     no match
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the header yourself if you really want one:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{b[$1]=$2;next} {$1=$1; print $0, b[$1], ($2==b[$1] ? "" : "no ") "match"}' B.txt A.txt
api     2.3     4.3     no match
java    3.3     4.5     no match
```